# Python requests login to website

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, build-automation

I can't seem to login to my university website using python requests.session() function. I have tried retrieving all the headers and cookies needed to login but it does not successfully log in with my credentials. It does not show any error but the source code I review after it is supposed to have logged in shows that it is still not logged in.

All my code is below. I fill the login and password with my credentials, but the rest is the exact code.

```
import requests

with requests.session() as r:
    url = "https://www.ouac.on.ca/apply/nonsecondary/intl/en_CA  /user/login"
    page = r.get(url)
    aspsessionid = r.cookies["ASPSESSIONID"]
    ouacapply1 = r.cookies["OUACApply1"]
    LOGIN = ""
    PASSWORD = ""
    login_data = dict(ASPSESSIONID=aspsessionid, OUACApply1=ouacapply1, login=LOGIN, password=PASSWORD)
    header = {"Referer":"https://www.ouac.on.ca/apply/nonsecondary/intl/en_CA/user/login", "User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:57.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/57.0"}
    logged_in = r.post(url, data=login_data, headers=header)
    new_page = r.get(url="https://www.ouac.on.ca/apply/nonsecondary/intl/en_CA/profile/")
    plain_text = new_page.text
    print(plain_text)
```

Comment: use `DevTool` in Chrome/Firefox to see all headers/cookies which browser sends to server.

Comment: BTW: why do you have spaces in url `intl/en_CA  /user/login` ?

Comment: ohh i think that was just when i copied and pasted my code, mustve been an accident. thank you for pointing that out

Answer (score 1):

You are missing two inputs which is needed to be posted -

1. `name='submitButton'`, `value='Log In'`
2. `name='csrf'`, `value=''`

The value for second keeps changing so you need to get its value dynamically.
If you want to see where this input is then goto the forms closing tag, just above the closing tag there you will find an input which hidden.

So include these two values in your login_data and you will be able to login.

Comment: Thank you TubbyStubby, but I cant seem to get the csrf value from the website as when i use requests.session().cookie["csrf"], it raises a KeyError and when i inspect the form element you are right, there is a hidden csrf value but it does not appear in the Headers or the Cookies sections when i look through the network tab in inspect element on firefox. It does however appear on the Params tab as 'csrf'.And yes i have tried entering "csrf", "csrftoekn" and even "csrfmiddlewaretoken" and they all return KeyError. Please help.  Thank you very much.